# Laravel database foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to users have a rank like user, admin, editor,... But I can't add foreign key to rank column in user table from rank table.

This is the ranks table migration

```
Schema::create('ranks', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->increments('id');
  $table->string('rank', 32)->charset('utf8')->nullable($value = false);
});
```

And this is the user table migration

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name', 64)->charset('utf8')->nullable($value = false);
    $table->string('email', 128)->unique()->charset('utf8')->nullable($value = false);
    $table->string('password', 128)->charset('utf8')->nullable($value = false);
    $table->integer('rank')->unsigned()->default(1);
    $table->foreign('rank')->references('id')->on('ranks')->nullable($value = false);
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Comment: `$table->foreign('rank')->references('id')->on('ranks')->nullable($value = false);` what does this line meaning?? why nullable()?? what is the error you are having?

Comment: Remove all `$value = false` and the default call on the rank integer column.

Comment: @Sohel0415 to make it that the collum cant be null ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `hots`.`#sql-268_5d
  df` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter
   table `users` add constraint `users_rank_foreign` foreign key (`rank`) ref
  erences `ranks` (`id`))

Comment: @Joel Hinz doesnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `users` table migration has `2014_10_12_000000` timestamp, so it is created before any migration that were created manually. So change the `ranks` table migration filename timestamp to create the table before the `users` table. For example:

```
2013_10_12_000000_create_ranks_table.php
2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php
```

Also, move FK constraint code to a separate closure:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name', 64)->charset('utf8')->nullable($value = false);
    $table->string('email', 128)->unique()->charset('utf8')->nullable($value = false);
    $table->string('password', 128)->charset('utf8')->nullable($value = false);
    $table->integer('rank')->unsigned()->default(1);
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreign('rank')->references('id')->on('ranks')->nullable();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your ranks are fixed a better design would be to add an `ENUM` field to the users table.

```
$table->enum('rank', [User::LEVEL_ADMIN, User::LEVEL_EDITOR]);
```

Where the constants are defined in the User class. You can then get rid of the rank table.

--

If you want to keep the ranks in a separated table to let administrators to manage them for example you can keep it but create tables first and add the foreign key later on.

Also, take advantage of Eloquent conventions and call the foreign key `rank_id` so you'll not need to specify it in the relationship method in the model.

```
Schema::create('ranks', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->increments('id');
  $table->string('rank', 32)->charset('utf8');
});

Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name', 64)->charset('utf8');
    $table->string('email', 128)->unique()->charset('utf8');
    $table->string('password', 128)->charset('utf8');
    $table->integer('rank_id')->unsigned();
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreign('rank_id')->references('id')->on('ranks');
});
```